# Unix: “ls” command shows files with ? after the extension

Tags: bash, unix, shell, file, java

I have written a shell script (test.sh) using Java. This shell script actually does a copy job from one file to the other. After the execution of the shell script I have opened the directory from Console and typed ls. It shows the output file with ? after the extension.

example : foo.csv?

```
File execFile = new File(file);
FileWriter fwFile;
try {
    fwFile = new FileWriter(execFile);
    execFile.setExecutable(true);
    BufferedWriter bwFile = new BufferedWriter(fwFile);
    bwFile.write(strOutput.substring(0, 2));
    bwFile.write("\r\n");
    bwFile.write("cd " + strOutput);
    bwFile.write("\r\n");
    bwFile.write("mkdir " + strOutput);
    bwFile.write("\r\n");
    bwFile.write(strUnixPath);
    bwFile.write("\r\n");
    bwFile.write("cd " + strWorkingPath + IPlatinumConstants.FS+"lib"+IPlatinumConstants.FS+"Unx");
    bwFile.write("\r\n");
    bwFile.write("echo Cut Src Start time %time%");
    bwFile.write("\r\n");

            bwFile.write("cp " + " \"" + strSourceFilePath + "\"  \""
                    + strOutput + "copy_A\"");
            bwFile.write("\r\n");
```

Comment: `ls` should **never** be used for any purpose other than display *to end users, for human consumption only*. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a description of (just some of) the things that can go wrong trying to use `ls` programatically.

Comment: Your program also has shell-injection security bugs as presently written -- if a directory had a name like `foo$(rm -rf $HOME)bar`, guess what happens when you invoke a shell against the buffer you wrote that into?

Answer (score 13):

My guess:

Your Java program is using `\r\n`, carriage return + line feed, to terminate each line. However, Unix systems use *only* the line feed `\n` as a new-line indicator. While the carriage return is understood by *terminals*, it has no meaning at all to other programs – it's just a character like any other as far as the `/bin/sh` interpreter is concerned. This means that the `\r` becomes part of the last parameter of each command that your script runs:

```
cd myoutput\r
mkdir myoutput\r
cd something/lib/something\r
echo Cut Src Start time %time%\r
cp "sourcefile" "myoutputcopy_A"\r
```

So the last command is always creating files that have the carriage-return at the end of their name, and `ls` shows them as a question mark like all other "unprintable" characters. You can see this using `ls -b` or `ls -Q`.

To fix this, use only `\n` when generating Unix shell scripts. (Or, even better, *don't* generate shell scripts – instead, write scripts that accept parameters where needed. You could do many things in the Java program itself, as well.)

Comment: I would actually assume that the script doesn't even `cd` where the OP wanted it to go. So, quite a mess.

Comment: To check whether this answer reflects the actual problem OP can run `ls | xxd` and see if there's `0d` after file name hex representation.

Comment: @Ruslan - Or use `ls -b`

Comment: @AFH oh, that's even cleaner

Comment: It's worth noting that `\n` can legitimately be used as a character within filenames, so using it as a character to delimit between filenames is doomed to failure.

Comment: Technically allowed, yes. _Legitimately_ used? Hah.